# How do I use external applications to scrape data from a mobile app?

Tags: python, web-scraping, mobile, fiddler, scrape

I am trying to scrape data from a mobile application (Pokemon HOME). The app shows usage statistics and other useful statistics that I want to scrape. I want to scrape this on my computer using python.

I am having trouble determining how to scrape data from a mobile application. I tried using Fiddler and an Android emulator to intercept server data but I am unfamiliar with the software to be able to understand what exactly to do.

Any help would be very beneficial. Even just suggestions for resources where I can learn how to do this on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it's really a hard nut to break. There's a huge difference between Mobile app and web app
Web app is accessible through WAN ,v.i.z World area network. **Scraping** is fairly and squarely easier.
In Python, you can bs4 to do it.
But in Mobile app, essentially and effectively, it's more about LAN.
It's installed locally.
Install an app to remote control your device from another device (usually required root)
However, whole data might not be available.

Comment: Maybe you should share some examples to  truly express how it is a "hard nut to break."